# How to achieve backref-like query in Node.js and sqlite?

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite

Short Version: Is there an application in Node.js that offers functionalities similar to Python-SQLAlchemy's backref?

What I actually want to achieve:
I have three sql tables: article, chapter and subchapter. One article has multiple chapters, and on chapter can contain multiple or zero subchapter.
With SQLAlchemy it's quite simple, in `models.py`

```
class Article(db.Model):
    ...
    chapters = db.relationship('Chapter', backref='mainArticle', lazy=True)

class Chapter(db.Model):
    ...
    articleID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('article.id'), nullable=False)
    subChapters = db.relationship('subChapter', backref='mainChapter', lazy=True)

class subChapter(db.Model):
    ...
    chapterID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('chapter.id'), nullable=False)
```

And then I can access even the attributes of Article from subChapter:

```
subchapter = subChapter.query.first()
subchapter.mainChapter.id # Returns the chapter ID
subchapter.mainChapter.mainArticle.id # Returns the article ID
```

I've been using SQLAlchemy so I'm not sure how to select with SQLite, I tried:

```
app.get('/test/:articleID', (req, res) => {
    let article_id = req.params.articleID;
    let sql = `SELECT article.*, chapter.*, subchapter.*
    FROM article 
    LEFT JOIN chapter ON article.id = chapter.articleID
    LEFT JOIN subchapter ON chapter.id = subchapter.chapterID
    WHERE article.id = ?`;
    db.get(sql, [article_id], (err, article) => {
        res.send(article)
    });
})
```

But it just spit out a bunch of null...

Unfortunately current situation forces me to use Node.js instead of Python, so is there any way to achieve a similar result in Node.js?

Comment: There should be something else wrong in your code, [a simple try with your query seems to work](https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-5c9de0701f09054xjttugfsj), hard to answer you without more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some trials and errors I figured out a not-so-elegant way (maybe an ugly way) to get the job done without any third-party application.
First we select ALL the rows of the database that are linked to a article number with `LEFT JOIN` method. The `null` problem seems to be caused by identical key name in different tables (i.e. `article.title, chapter.title, subchapter.title`), so just distinguish them with `AS` method.

```
SELECT article.title, 
    chapter.title AS cT, chapter.chapterNumber AS cN,
    subchapter.title AS scT, subchapter.subChapterNumber AS scN
FROM article 
LEFT JOIN chapter ON article.id = chapter.articleID
LEFT JOIN subchapter ON chapter.id = subchapter.chapterID
WHERE article.id = 1
ORDER BY
    chapterNumber ASC,
    subChapterNumber ASC
```

This will get a bunch of entries **where every subchapter is shown once, every chapter is shown at least once, depending on the subchapters it has**.

Now we can write an iteration to sort the data. The fundamental idea is to form an `article` object, with a `chapter` property that contains an array of chapter objects, each one contains a `subchapter` property populated with an array of its own subchapter objects:

```
article = {
    "title": "Article Title",
    "chapters": [
        {
            "chapterNumber": 1,
            "subchapters": [
                {
                    "subchapterNumber": 1,
                },
                {
                    "subchapterNumber": 2,
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "chapterNumber": 2,
            "subchapters": []
        },
    ]
}
```

Then we can simply use `article.chapters[0]` to access the chapter 1, and use `article.chapters[0].subchapters[0]` to get chapter 1.1.

To achieve this, the iteration to organise the data would be:

```
article = {"title":entries[0].title, "chapters":[]};
    // First create all the chapter entries for subchapters to depend on.
    for (i in entries) {
        // Use underscore.js utility to determine if this chapter has already been put in.
        if (_.findWhere(article.chapters, {"chapterNumber":entries[i].cN}) == null) {
            // Create a new chapter entry.
            article.chapters.push({"chapterNumber":entries[i].cN,  "subchapters":[]})
        }
    };
    // Then put in place all the subchapters.
    for (i in entries) {
        // Only analyse all the entries that contain a subchapter.
        if (entries[i].scN){
            // Find the corresponding chapter
            chapter = _.findWhere(article.chapters, {"chapterNumber":entries[i].cN})
            // Determine if this subchapter has already been put in.
            if (_.findWhere(chapter.subchapters, {"subchapterNumber":entries[i].scN}) == null) {
                // Create a new subchapter entry.
                chapter.subchapters.push({"chapterNumber":entries[i].cN, "subchapterNumber":entries[i].scN})
            }
        }
    };
```

The same principal still applies if the database is more complicated, like if every subchapter contains zero to multiple secondary subchapters.

Now a single `article` object contains all the informations we can possibly need to display an article in its order. A simple run with pug to display the schema would be:

```
html
    head
        title= article.title
    body
        each chapter in article.chapters
            li= chapter.title
            each subchapter in chapter.subchapters
                li(style="padding-left:30px")= subchapter.title
```

This might not be quite efficient, but it at least get the job done. Please tell me if you know any better solution. Happy coding to everyone!